# Check which registered sidebar a widget is added to

Tags: widgets, taxonomy, sidebar

I have 2 registered sidebars in my theme one for **Products** and one for **Blog.**

What I am trying to do is if my "Category" widget is added to the Product Sidebar the taxonomy is automatically set to "product_cats" and if added to the Blog Sidebar set the taxonomy to "category". This will allow my widget on the backend to update which categories it displays in the dropdown menu.

I have been searching the **wp-includes/widgets.php** file for a method or property that contains the id or name of the Parent Sidebar of the widget but can't seem to find a way to do this.

If I can get the name or id of the Parent Sidebar I would do something like this in the form method of my widget:

```
public function form( $instance ) {

    $parent = getParentSidebarID($this); // How do you do this!

    switch ($parent) {
        case 'product-sidebar':
            $tax = 'product_cat';
            break;
        case 'blog-sidebar':
            $tax = 'category';
            break;
        default:
            $tax = '';
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a standard way to do it AFAIK in the form() method; here's a function to do it:

```
function wp158055_get_sidebar_id( $widget ) {
    foreach ( wp_get_sidebars_widgets() as $sidebar_id => $widget_ids ) {
        if ( array_search( $widget->id, $widget_ids ) !== false ) return $sidebar_id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call with `$this`. Note from the widget() method you can use `$args['id']` as mentioned [in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58915/57034).